# SAS YYMMDD10. works but YYMMDDn10 doesn't

Tags: sql, datetime, sas, format, put

This is my data (sorry for no script, it's just proc create table from mssql):

```
testdb.testtable
id - numeric
date_from - numeric (datetime from mssql)
date_to - numeric (datetime from mssql)
base_id - numeric
base_id2 - string (length 64)
```

What I tried to do was:

```
proc sql;
update testdb.testtable tt
set base_id2 = CATX('_',
    ('data from other table'),
    put(datepart(date_from),yymmddn10.),
    put(datepart(date_to),yymmddn10.),
    put(base_id,z4.)
)
where (....)
;
quit;
```

And I get this error:

```
The width value for YYMMDDN is out of bounds. It should be between 2 and 8.
The width value for YYMMDDN is out of bounds. It should be between 2 and 8.
```

What I really don't understand is that when I use format with separators, YYMMDD10., it works.

When i run:

```
proc sql;
select datepart(date_from) format=yymmddn10. from testdb.testtable;
quit;
```

It returns 20191227 - It's great. When I run

```
proc sql;
select put(datepart(date_from),yymmddn10.) from testdb.testtable;
quit;
```

It fails with the same error.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in PROC SQL that allows you to attach a format that cannot work (the maximum width needed for a date without separators is 8 bytes).

It is also interesting that PROC PRINT (and the simple SELECT query in PROC SQL, like in your example) do not mind that the format width is invalid.

```
542   data test1;
543     now=date();
544   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST1 has 1 observations and 1 variables.

545
546   data test2 ;
547     set test1;
548     format now yymmddn10.;
                   ----------
                   29
ERROR 29-185: Width specified for format YYMMDDN is invalid.

549   run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.TEST2 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations
         and 1 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.TEST2 was not replaced because this step was stopped.

550
551   proc sql;
552   create table test2 as select now format=yymmddn10. from test1;
NOTE: Table WORK.TEST2 created, with 1 rows and 1 columns.

553   select * from test2;
554   quit;


555
556   proc print data=test2;
557   run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.TEST2.

558
559   data test3;
560     set test2;
561   run;

ERROR: Width specified for format YYMMDDN is invalid.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.TEST3 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations
         and 1 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.TEST3 was not replaced because this step was stopped.
```

Also interesting is that if you use that format specification in PROC FREQ

```
proc freq data=test2; tables now; run;
```

it adds a space and a 'F7'x character in front of the data string.

```
The FREQ Procedure

                                       Cumulative    Cumulative
       now    Frequency     Percent     Frequency      Percent
---------------------------------------------------------------
 ÷20200218           1      100.00             1       100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

The number in format is the given width. Format YYMMDDn has 8 chars, so I should have used YYMMDDn8. And it worked.

I was having a long struggle with it and I still don't understand why did it work in format= and not in put().